# Why does the outer <div> here not completely surround the inner <div>?

Tags: html, css

I've got a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh7qbye2/7/

And a test web page here: https://shetline.com/test/test01.html

The question is this: Why doesn't the content of the inner `<div>` prevent the outer `<div>` from shrinking to less than the width of the inner `<div>` when you resize the containing window to a narrow size?

[image: sample image of inner div escaping outer div]

> Updates based on the answer I got for the problem:
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/Lh7qbye2/8/
>
> https://shetline.com/test/test02.html

I can solve the problem for Chrome or Safari by using:

`width: fit-content;`

...on the outer `<div>`, but this doesn't solve the problem for Firefox or Edge. Further, MDN marks `fit-content` as an [experimental API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width):

> This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code.

`word-break: break-all` on the outer `<div>` kinda, sorta, helps, but messes up all word wrap. If I try to compensate by setting `normal` breaking on the `<p>` and `<button>` tags, the help provided by the outer `break-all` disappears.

One thing that really confuses me is that I know I've seen situations like this with no spill-over problem at all, and I didn't have to go out of my way to get the behavior I'd expect. What am I missing that's wrong in this simplified example?

```css
body {
  margin: 4em;
}

.demo {
  background-color: #BFC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  /* width: fit-content; // With this it works for Chrome or Safari, but not for Firefox or Edge. */
  /* word-break: break-all; // For some reason this sort of helps too, but of course messes up all word wrapping. */
  /* If I try to apply "word-break: normal" to <p> and <button> tags to compensate, the inner <div> leaks out again. */
}

.demo p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.other-stuff {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #AEB;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #699;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #969;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="other-stuff">
    <button>One&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <button>Another&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button>Don't&nbsp;click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `flex-wrap: wrap` so that the flexing items will wrap, or you could add `overlfow: scroll` so they can be horizontal scrolled. Otherwise, this is expected behavior - there is no more room for the elements that must fit, so they flow outside of their parent container.

Comment: Shouldn't the outer div simply stop shrinking if its inner contents need more room? (I explained below why flex-wrap isn't the answer I'm looking for.) I'm pretty sure I've seen <div>s behave that way before, I just don't know why it's not happening here.

Comment: because block element is by default width:100% of its parent so its width is not defined by its content. Use inline-block and you will have what you want

Comment: Thanks, Temani! Post that as an official answer, and I'll definitely mark it as the solution! :)

Comment: as a side note, the issue start with `other-stuff` .. add background to it and you will see the overflow there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can be done using a combination of `inline-block` and `min-width:100%`. A block element has its width defined based on its parent element (containing block) while `inline-block` will have its width defined by its content.

Adding the `min-width:100%` will make it behave as block element. it's not mandatory in this case since you already have a lot of content so you are sure to cover all the width:

```css
body {
  margin: 4em;
}

.demo {
  background-color: #BFC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:100%;
}

.demo p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.other-stuff {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #699;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #969;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="other-stuff">
    <button>One&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <button>Another&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button>Don't&nbsp;click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reduce the text on the top and `min-width:100%` will become mandatory to have full width behavior.

<sup>Run the snippet on full page</sup>

```css
body {
  margin: 4em;
}

.demo {
  background-color: #BFC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.demo p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.other-stuff {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #699;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #969;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <div class="other-stuff">
    <button>One&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <button>Another&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button>Don't&nbsp;click!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="demo" style="min-width:100%;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <div class="other-stuff">
    <button>One&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <button>Another&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button>Don't&nbsp;click!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html):

> Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow
>
> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> ```
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
> ```

<sup>Note how the content play no role in defining the width.</sup>

> 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow
>
> If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the shrink-to-fit width
>
> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting **the content** without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant scroll bars
>
> the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`

<sup>Note how the content is used to define the width.</sup>

---

The same apply to any kind of display value (`grid`, `flex`, `table`, etc) and the trick is to replace it with the `inline-*` equivalent (`inline-grid`, `inline-flex`, `inline-table`, etc)

Comment: I didn't have a chance until today to try this with Edge. Unfortunately with Edge, using `inline-block` doesn't help, even when also adding `width: 100%`. Where `inline-block` is working for me, `width: 100%` doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: @kshetline I am pretty sure you have an issue related to the flexbox. I don't think inline-block can create bug in Edge but flexbox can

Comment: flex-box might be part of the problem, but I've tried change that "other-stuff" class to use inline-flex, block, inline-block, and I've tried giving an explicit width and/or min-width... and the outer div with class "demo" does not care! No matter what I've tried so far, with Edge I can't get a div to care about the width of its content, no matter what I've tried.

Comment: @kshetline maybe it deserve a new question. You probably discovered a bug. I cannot help as I don't have Edge to test with

Comment: Or I can just wait for the current Edge browser to die a natural death . I tried this issue with the now-beta Chromium-based Edge, and it works just fine there. The main problem I'm working on is responsive layouts, and nobody's probably going to be using Edge on a tiny screen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to break the contents to the next line.

In saying that, since you are using fixed width for `buttons`, this is your best option in smaller screens.

```css
body {
  margin: 4em;
}

.demo {
  background-color: #BFC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.demo p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.other-stuff {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #699;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #969;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="other-stuff">
    <button>One&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <button>Another&nbsp;button</button>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <button>Don't&nbsp;click!</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're missing the point of what I'm going for. I don't want the inner <div> to wrap more and get narrower. (In many situations that would be desirable, yes, but that's not the point of this example.) I want the outer <div> to *stop shrinking* when it gets down to the width of the inner <div>.