# How do I make parent container and other child in Flex to grow as one of the longest child

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to the container and the green div to grow as the same size as blue whenever things inside the blue div grow.

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.normal {
  background: green;
}

.wide {
  width: 2500px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="wide">Wide</div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/terencetcf/pen/ExaEZzR)

Comment: What do you mean "grow"? Vertically, horizontally? Are you saying that if blue div has content that makes it 400px high, the green container should also be 400px high even when empty?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but I think what you mean is this: `display: inline-flex;`

Comment: `width: max-content;` in container seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider `inline-flex` instead

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width:100%; /*to make sure it behave like flex if the content is small*/
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.normal {
  background: green;
}

.wide {
  width: 2500px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal">Normal</div>
  <div class="wide">Wide</div>
</div>
```

Related: [Why does the outer <div> here not completely surround the inner <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57600615/8620333)