# Element's border bottom is cut off inside of a horizontal container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a horizontally scrollable container that consists of divs (rows) where each row has its own border bottom. It works but when I start horizontally scrolling the container I see the border is being cut, that's related to the row having 100% width of the container width.

Is there a way to fix it without using pixel values (and JS), since the width of a row is fully dynamic?

```css
.table {
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
.table {
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /*white-space: nowrap; not needed */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: inline-flex; /* update */
  min-width:100%; /* added */
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related question: [Why does the outer <div> here not completely surround the inner <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57600615/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `width:max-content;` to allow it to grow past the 100% of width *(default behavior of a block element)* of its parent (like a table would do).

example :)

```css
.table {
  width: 350px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
  width:max-content;
 /* eventually  min-width:100% */
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
</div>
```